# To get subset of dataframe based on index of a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe from yahoo finance

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance
ticker = yfinance.Ticker("INFY.NS")
df = ticker.history(period = '1y')
print(df)
```

This gives me df as,

[image]

If I specify,

```
date = "2021-04-23"
```

- I need a subset of df with row having indexes label "2021-04-23"
- rows of 2 days before the date
- row of 1 day after of date

The important thing here is, we cannot calculate before & after using date strings as df may not have some dates but rows to be printed based on indexes. (i.e. 2 rows of previous indexes and one row of next index)
For example, in df, there is no "2021-04-21" but "2021-04-20"

How can we implement this?

Comment: Wahts happens if not exist `2021-04-23` in `DatetimeIndex` ? Or it never happens?

Comment: I Will catch that exception.

Comment: are the bullet points misworded? i think you meant `2 rows before the date` instead of `rows of 2 days before the date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for integer-based indexing. First find the integer location of the desired `date` and then take the desired subset with `iloc`:

```py
def get_subset(df, date):
    # get the integer index of the matching date(s)
    matching_dates_inds, = np.nonzero(df.index == date)
    
    # and take the first one (works in case of duplicates)
    first_matching_date_ind = matching_dates_inds[0]
    
    # take the 4-element subset
    desired_subset = df.iloc[first_matching_date_ind - 2: first_matching_date_ind + 2]

    return desired_subset
```

Comment: nice! maybe just `first_matching_date_ind = np.nonzero(df.index == date)[0][0]`? though it is easier to understand as 2 lines

Comment: thanks @tdy!  Agreed; `[0][0]` seemed a little cryptic `:)` but a comment would clarify perhaps. All because of `nonzero` giving a 1-tuple for 1D array!

Answer (score 3):

If need before and after values by positions (if always exist `date` in `DatetimeIndex`) use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with position by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) with `min` and `max` for select rows if not exist values before `2` or after `1` like in sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}, 
                   index=pd.to_datetime(['2021-04-21','2021-04-23','2021-04-25']))

date = "2021-04-23"
pos = df.index.get_loc(date)
df = df.iloc[max(0, pos-2):min(len(df), pos+2)]
print (df)
            a
2021-04-21  1
2021-04-23  2
2021-04-25  3
```

*Notice:
`min` and `max` are added for not failed selecting if date is first (not exist 2 values before, or second - not exist second value before) or last (not exist value after)*

Comment: Only one date will be given, other dates and rows to be found automatically.

Comment: in both solutions, you have mentioned dates In pd.  For "2021-04-23" date, other date rows will be automatically calculated.

Comment: @sam - Yes, it is in both my solutions. Question is if need count datimes like in first solution or like in second, both are diifferent

Comment: we cant do before 2 days, what if there is no row for that day. It might happen that its a holiday for stocks. Thus we need index values.

Comment: @sam - So use second solution similar like another answer, only working if `2021-04-23` is first date , second date or last date in `DatetimeIndex` (added `min, max`) for not failed.